# Runtime Error Submitting an answer

Tags: bug, status-completed

Here is the question: [node.js POST request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3192652)

Here was the answer I was trying to submit(After another try it was submitted without any error):

```
For more easier client requests you can use [request](https://github.com/mikeal/request) module. It takes care of all the hard work and has a simple API.
```

Here is the location after submitting:

https://stackoverflow.com/error?aspxerrorpath=/questions/3192652/answer/submit

Here is the error message:

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
Runtime Error

Description: An application error occurred on the server. The current custom error settings for this application prevent the details of the application error from being viewed remotely (for security reasons). It could, however, be viewed by browsers running on the local server machine. 

Details: To enable the details of this specific error message to be viewable on remote machines, please create a <customErrors> tag within a "web.config" configuration file located in the root directory of the current web application. This <customErrors> tag should then have its "mode" attribute set to "Off".


<!-- Web.Config Configuration File -->

<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <customErrors mode="Off"/>
    </system.web>
</configuration>

Notes: The current error page you are seeing can be replaced by a custom error page by modifying the "defaultRedirect" attribute of the application's <customErrors> configuration tag to point to a custom error page URL.


<!-- Web.Config Configuration File -->

<    configuration>
    <system.web>
        <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="mycustompage.htm"/>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Hmm..? I see your answer here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3192652/node-js-post-request/7781910#7781910

Comment: I tried again and it worked. The first try it showed this error above.

Comment: Either temporary glitch or deploying new version - I won't call that "bug" unless it happens again or can be reproduced.

Comment: Well you can edit the post and the tags. If I face it again but not be able to reproduce, not supposed to report it again?

Comment: @FaridNeshat - If you can reproduce a bug consistently, then report it!  If it happens repeatably but you're not sure why, post everything you know about what makes it happen and someone with more knowledge about possible problems can try to reproduce it.  If it happens once, and you have no idea what could have caused it or could cause it to happen again, it's not a very useful bug report.

Comment: Maybe we should have a specific tag for errors or bugs like this. I kinda don't like the idea of NOT reporting it but of course it's not useful. Or maybe a separate section for bugs like this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We had some network craziness with `ny-web04` (one of our web tier servers) around this time that was affecting its ability to communicate with `ny-db01` (one of our DB Tier servers).

It has been given a swift kick and should be behaving now.